# Should we @Override an interface's method implementation?

Tags: java, oop, interface, annotations

Should a method that implements an interface method be annotated with `@Override`?

The [javadoc of the `Override` annotation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) says:

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass. If a method is annotated with this annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers are required to generate an error message.

I don't think that an interface is technically a superclass. Or is it?

<kbd>[Question Elaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/212614/5)</kbd>

Comment: I can't find the replacement for the @Override article (Oracle moved the old Sun blogs recently).  Do you know how to find it?

Comment: We should have an @Implement(s) annotation by now (2015). That will make things clear!

Comment: by now (2015) should we use @Override with java 8?

Answer (score 343, accepted):

You should use `@Override` whenever possible.  It prevents simple mistakes from being made.  Example:

```
class C {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(SomeClass obj){
        // code ...
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because it doesn't properly override [`public boolean equals(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

The same will go for methods that implement an interface (**1.6 and above only**) or override a Super class's method.

Comment: Note that you **cannot** add the @Override annotation to a method implementing an interface in Java 5 - it generates an error. It is allowed in Java 6.

Comment: Um, no, it doesn't.  In fact, Eclipse auto-inserts @Override when filling in methods that implement an interface.

Comment: -1 until the answer includes a mention about the different behaviour from Java 1.5 to 1.6 with regards to implementing an interface method. Just because I've seen it be a confusing aspect for people and it really merits a mention.

Comment: Fixed...I guess I figure everyone uses the latest version of Java.  My bad.

Comment: +1 for the after 1.5 bit. Took me like 20 minutes to figure out why eclipse was giving me errors and with this I realized my new project was using java 1.5

Comment: If eclipse is complaining then upgrade ur jdk to > 1.5 and change the compiler compliance level to 1.6 or 1.7. To do that right click on ur project-> properties-> Java compiler and select one that is higher than 1.5.

Comment: Can anyone think of an example that actually justifies the answer (implementing interfaces rather than overriding base methods)?  A big plus for me is that it aids sets a readers expectations of how and by what a particular method might be used.

Comment: Eclipse does not allow the @Override notation for methods that are not inherited by a superclass.

Comment: this rule makes no sense to me. unless im wrong, interfaces tell us what functions are needed, not what's fully defined. essentially, there's nothing to override cuz it hasn't happened yet. i would personally only want to put it for superclass methods. not only that, all public methods now have @Override if you follow java's testing practice recommendations for creating an interface all the time

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Object is not an interface.

Comment: Although encouraged, annotations are completely optional. It's metadata!

Comment: @NoName If you put an "Override" annotation on something that is not overriden, it will not build. That's what this answer is saying. This way, you are making sure that you are really overriding a method, and not creating a new one if you mispelled the method name or something.

Answer (score 118):

I believe that javac behaviour has changed - with 1.5 it prohibited the annotation, with 1.6 it doesn't. The annotation provides an extra compile-time check, so if you're using 1.6 I'd go for it.

Answer (score 83):

You should always annotate methods with `@Override` if it's available.

In JDK 5 this means overriding methods of superclasses, in JDK 6, and 7 it means overriding methods of superclasses, and implementing methods of interfaces. The reason, as mentioned previously, is it allows the compiler to catch errors where you think you are overriding (or implementing) a method, but are actually defining a new method (different signature).

The `equals(Object)` vs. `equals(YourObject)` example is a standard case in point, but the same argument can be made for interface implementations.

I'd imagine the reason it's not mandatory to annotate implementing methods of interfaces is that JDK 5 flagged this as a compile error. If JDK 6 made this annotation mandatory, it would break backwards compatibility.

I am not an Eclipse user, but in other IDEs (IntelliJ), the `@Override` annotation is only added when implementing interface methods if the project is set as a JDK 6+ project. I would imagine that Eclipse is similar.

However, I would have preferred to see a different annotation for this usage, maybe an `@Implements` annotation.

Answer (score 17):

I would use it at every opportunity.   See [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Answer (score 12):

JDK 5.0 does not allow you to use `@Override` annotation if you are implementing method declared in interface (its compilation error), but JDK 6.0 allows it. So may be you can configure your project preference according to your requirement.

Answer (score 7):

By reading the javadoc in java8, you can find the following at the declaration of interface Override:

If a method is annotated with this annotation type compilers are required to generate an error message unless at least one of the following conditions hold:

- The method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype.
- The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public method declared in {@linkplain Object}.

So, at least in java8, you should use @Override on an implementation of an interface method.

Answer (score 6):

If a **concrete** class is not **overriding** an abstract method, using `@Override` for **implementation** is an open matter since the compiler will invariably warn you of any unimplemented methods. In these cases, an argument can be made that it detracts from readability -- it is more things to read on your code and, to a lesser degree, it is called `@Override` and not `@Implement`.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding your own methods inherited from your own classes will typically not break on refactorings using an ide. But if you override a method inherited from a library it is recommended to use it. If you dont, you will often get no error on a later library change, but a well hidden bug.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with JDK. In Eclipse Helios, it allows the @Override annotation for implemented interface methods, whichever JDK 5 or 6. As for Eclipse Galileo, the @Override annotation is not allowed, whichever JDK 5 or 6.

Answer (score 3):

If the class that is implementing the `interface` is an `abstract` class, `@Override` is useful to ensure that the implementation is for an `interface` method; without the  `@Override` an `abstract` class would just compile fine even if the implementation method signature does not match the method declared in the `interface`; the mismatched `interface` method would remain as unimplemented.
The Java doc cited by @Zhao

> The method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype

is clearly referring to an `abstract` super class; an `interface` can not be called the supertype.
So, `@Override` is redundant and not sensible for `interface` method implementations in concrete classes.

Comment: It is more than redundant. In STS4, when a class method implementing interface method was decorated with @Override, compiler error message says "...must override a superclass method".

Answer (score 2):

For me, often times this is the only reason some code requires Java 6 to compile. Not sure if it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with including the `@Override` is that it makes you think that you forgot to call the `super.theOverridenMethod()` method, which is *very confusing*.  This should be crystal-clear.  Perhaps Java should offer an `@Interface` to be used here.  Oh well, yet another half-assed Java peculiarity...

Comment: Calling a super, when not implementing an interface, is not something you always need to or want to do. Sometimes, you're adding functionality -- so you call it. Other times, you're replacing functionality, so you don't call it. An API author should document whether it relies on internal functionality or not and create a documented contract on how the class can be properly extended.

Answer (score 2):

In java 6 and later versions, you can use `@Override` for a method implementing an interface.

But, I donot think it make sense: override means you hava a method in the super class, and you are implementing it in the sub class.

If you are implementing an interface, I think we should use `@Implement` or something else, but not the `@Override`.

Comment: I agree, no other answer really justify why @override should used for an interface implementation. The only reason I'd say it could be useful is if you'd change a class to an abstract class, that reasonably speaking, should not happen.

Answer (score 2):

This might be too late answer. But I hope this example would help someone to understand why `@override` is so important (for a scenario like this)

```
public interface Restaurant(){
    public boolean getBill();
    public BigDecimal payAmount();
}

public interface Food() extends Restaurant{
    public boolean haveSomeFood();
    public boolean drinkWater();
}

public class Hungry() implements Food{
    public boolean haveSomeFood(){}
    public boolean drinkWater(){}
    public boolean getBill(){}
    public BigDecimal payAmount(){}
}
```

In the above example, If I am `Hungry`, I can have `Food` from a `Restaurant`. But if I took out the implementation of Restaurant, I do not have to get a bill and no need to pay the amount!!!!

**How?**

- The interface `Food` has the keyword `extends Restaurant` - which
  means the class Hungry is also implemented from the interface
  Restaurant.
- The methods actually overriden from the interface *does
  not* have the keyword `@override`
- So, if I remove the keyword extends
  Restaurant (or say if I remove the interface Restaurant, it will not
  show any error.

If there was `@override`, whenever I am trying to remove the Restaurant interface it will show compilation error.

**Note**: When you implement an interface, you might not know whether that interface is extended to another interface or can be extended or the inheritance may be removed. So it is always better to use `@override` keyword

Comment: Isn't it a very bad design to use `inheritance` to model the relationship between food and restaurant at first place? There is another way called `composition`. We shall never rely on the mighty power of a language to overcome the challenge brought by impotent design

Comment: @RuiZheng - Doesn't matter the design as the OP asked about override - `Should we @Override an interface's method implementation?`. I just wanted to describe why `@Override` is important. Of course, you are right, `food` can have from a `restaurant` or from `home` or from anywhere!. In my example, the tight coupling between food & restaurant is wrong. Thank you for noticing it (but I already thought about this scenario, didn't want to confuse describing those here)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse itself will add the `@Override` annotation when you tell it to "generate unimplemented methods" during creation of a class that implements an interface.