# Add warning for missing @Override annotation for interface implementation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4, java-6

In Eclipse 3.4.1 using JDK1.6.0_10 how can I activate a warning on a missing `@Override` annotation on a method that implements an interface method?

In the Preferences window this option:

> Java > Compiler > Errors / Warnings >
>   Annotations > Missing '@Override'
>   annotation

works fine for missing annotations on methods that override a superclass method, but it does nothing for interface methods.

Comment: Java 5 and Java 6 have different expectations about @Override annotations on interface implementations. I don't recall how this impacts Eclipse, but I know that it does.

Comment: I should have mentioned this. Added the version of Java (6) to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible in Eclipse 3.4.1. It is a [known issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163194). See this bug report page for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Belay what I said in the other thread. Apparently it's not a compiler option, but a Java compatibility version issue: if your compatibility version is 5, you won't be able to annotate interface implementation methods. If your compatibility version is 6, then you will be able to.

However I don't think there's a way of actually forcing Eclipse to generate an error if you do not annotate each implemented method. From [this page](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm):

> Missing '@Override' annotation: When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning whenever it encounters a method overriding another implemented method, and the '@Override' annotation is missing.

Comment: I use java 6 (edited the question to make this clear. Should have done that before.)

Comment: do you know if it can be done nowadays eclipse 4.4.1?

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility setting to 1.6 instead of 1.5 worked for me on:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Build id: 20100218-1602

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but interface methods are already required to be implemented by implementation classes.

The compiler will generate an error if the interface is not completely implemented.

Comment: Yes, but you still want this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-a-method-that-implements-an-interface-method-be-annotated-with-override

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the pointer. Must have missed that since I'm still at Java 1.5 on Mac OSX :-)