# How to find all methods overriding superclass/interface methods without @Override annotation?

Tags: java, search, methods, annotations, overriding

It's clear that having `@Override` annotation on overriding methods is a good practice. Is there an automatic way of finding all methods that miss the `@Override` annotation in a project? A script, search technique in any IDE would help

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224945/add-warning-for-missing-override-annotation-for-interface-implementation-in-ecli

Comment: You could always write a tool to manually inspect the .class files. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse shows warnings if you are missing `@Override`. You can go to:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Annotations
```

You can choose to have warning or even error for "Missing `@Override` annotation".

Answer (score 5):

In IntelliJ IDEA open Settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in Inspections open Class Structure -> 'Missing @Override annotation'

For version 15.0.3 and newer: Editor > Inspections > Java > Inheritance Issues > Missing @ Override (via @skubski)

Comment: This now is under Editor > Inspections > Java > Inheritance Issues > Missing @ Override (Using IJ 15.0.3)

Answer (score 4):

In Netbeans, right click the project, select Inspect and Transform, select "Add @Override Annotation" from the Single Inspection combo-box, hit Inspect, then Refactor.