# java 7 alternative to default methods in interface (only in Java 8)

Tags: java

I wanted to use default methods in one of my interface classes - then I realised that this is only available in Java 8 - and we are using Java 7.

What is the best way of achieving similar in Java 7 ?

Comment: What is the big picture, why do you need default methods?

Comment: Use an abstract class instead.

Comment: Because I don't want to have to change a lot of classes ... the reason that default methods were added I guess

Comment: @NottmTony There was no sensible way of interface evolution before default methods. Abstract classes or creating an additional interface for the new methods only are two examples of the workarounds people used.

Comment: @biziclop - thanks - might add another interface - still considering ...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What if there's an inheritance logic behind its classes?

Comment: @NottmTony Here's a really ugly example of this: [LayoutManager2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager2.html)

Comment: [You may want to look at the Composite Pattern if you want to have multiple instances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your methods signature in an interface, as in Java 8.
Have your method default implementation in an abstract class implementing that interface.
Have your method final implementation in a class extending that abstract class.

Now you have to be aware that it will still not be the same as having Java 8's interfaces' default method, in particular because you cannot extend multiple abstract class, while you can implement multiple interfaces with their default methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one option for that in java 7 , use abstract class.