# NotImplementedError Django Command

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I created a simple django command and when I want to test it from the command line (terminal) I get a NotImplementedError.

My code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import logging
from datetime import date, timedelta

logger = logging.getLogger('dataimport')


class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    def handele_noargs(self, **options):
        # Sending all the errors
        logger.info("test")
```

The error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 11, in 
>       execute_manager(settings)
>
> File "/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 459, in execute_manager
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 382, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>
> File "/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
>
> File "/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>
> File "/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
>       return self.handle_noargs(**options)
>
> File "/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 378, in handle_noargs
>       raise NotImplementedError()
>
> NotImplementedError

Comment: Apparently, simple typos are now off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
def handele_noargs(self, **options):
```

should be:

```
def handle_noargs(self, **options):
```

One could only dream of having Java `@Override` annotation in Python.
Or one could write it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313042/1240162

Comment: Damn, I looked at it for ages but still couldn't see a stupid typo, thanks :)