# Overriding the decorator of an abstract class in the inherited class

Tags: python, abstract-class, decorator, python-decorators, abc

So here's what I have:

The abstract class:

```
class DataWrapper(object):
    def decorator(f):
        def preprocess(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return preprocess

    @decorator
    def datamethod1(self, ..): ...

    @decorator
    def datamethod2(self, ..): ...
```

The inheriting class:

```
class DataManipulation(DataWrapper):
    def __init__(self, ..): ..

    def decorator(f):
        print 'here'
        def preprocess(*args, **kwargs):
            ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return preprocess
```

Essentially I have a bunch of general data methods (defined in DataWrapper) which are used by various classes. I allow a decorator to be defined to perform any pre / post processing on the data before being returned, which is defined in DataWrapper just as a placeholder.

Unfortunately, the decorator isn't being overridden when I try defining it in inherited classes; i.e. 'here' is not being printed.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167617/in-python-how-do-i-indicate-im-overriding-a-method) and tried adding the override decorator in the inherited class, and while there's no error, 'here' still is not being printed.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorators are applied to functions *when the class is defined*, their return values *replace* the functions they decorated. By the time the `DataWrapper` class has been defined, you can no longer alter what decorator is being used.

Rather than use decorators, have the decorator delegate to another method on the class that subclasses can override:

```
def method_process(f):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.process(f, *args, **kwargs)                

class DataWrapper(object):
    def process(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        # subclass to process the methods
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

    @method_process
    def datamethod1(self, ..):
        # ...

    @method_process
    def datamethod2(self, ..):
        # ...


class DataManipulation(DataWrapper):    
    def process(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'preprocessing here'
        return super(DataManipulation, self).process(f, *args, **kwargs)
```