# Python decorators - Where do parameters come from?

Tags: python, overriding, python-decorators

I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167617/in-python-how-do-i-indicate-im-overriding-a-method) and the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313042/1829329) answer.

Quote:

```
def overrides(interface_class):
    def overrider(method):
        assert(method.__name__ in dir(interface_class))
        return method
    return overrider
```

However, I am still not sure, where the parameter `method` comes from, if I override an arbitrary method.

I'll try to explain what I've understood so far:

1. The outer function gets its parameter from the notation of the decorator. The decorator gets one parameter, which is the interface, from which we get the method we want to override.
2. <strike>The result of the decorator is a `function`, which will replace the function, which we decorate with this decorator.</strike>
3. The assert statement checks if the method we want to override is really in the interface, which we gave as a parameter. This is what the actual use is, because now we cannot override not existing methods. If we still try to do this, we will have a failed assertion.

But I still don't get where the parameter `method` comes from and why it is always the method and not the instance, of the class, in which we want to override a method. A class' method usually has `self` as a parameter and that refers to the instance, or is that wrong?

I've also read [this](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) website. Seems like in their example, the decorator has to take the same parameters the decorated function takes.

So how comes we suddenly have the method and not the class as a parameter?

**EDIT#1:**
On [this website](http://scottlobdell.me/2015/04/decorators-arguments-python/) I found examples, where the outer function receives the function, which will be decorated, instead of the parameters for that function or the decorator. It seems the logic of how decorators work is dependent on the condition if there are arguments to the decoration or not. But what are those rules?

Example from that website:

```
def pass_thru(func_to_decorate):
    def new_func(*original_args, **original_kwargs):
        print "Function has been decorated.  Congratulations."
        # Do whatever else you want here
        return func_to_decorate(*original_args, **original_kwargs)
    return new_func


# Notice nothing here now
def print_args(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg


# Notice the change here
pass_thru(print_args)(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: when a callee loves a caller very much they get together and make little parameters, that the stork then drops off in the parenthesis

Comment: @JoranBeasley are you saying, that when a method is called, for example like this: `foo(self)` it becomes `foo, self` where the first parameter is always the method name and `self` becomes a message to the method with the method name `foo`?

Comment: no sorry I was basically just being a smart ass :/  ... the title made me think of "where do babies come from?"

Answer (score 1):

Your second point is not valid:

> 2. The result of the decorator is a `function`, which will replace the function, which we decorate with this decorator.

Technically `overrides` returns the decorator to use for the method. Instead of

```
class Class(object):
    @overrides(Interface)
    def method(self):
        pass
```

you could just write

```
class Class(object):
    overrider = overrides(Interface)
    @overrider
    def method(self):
        pass
```

As you can find in the [motivation for decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#motivation), you'll have a construct equivalent to something like

```
class Class(object):
    def method(self):
        pass
    method = overrides(Interface)(method)
```

Comment: I see. Ok, so I've got that decorator as a return value, but how would you describe, how the decorator is applied to the decorated function?

Comment: @Zelphir hope this helps

Comment: That'd explain where `method` comes from, but I still don't understand the examples on http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/ then. Why can they use `name`? `name` is not the method, so it seems there is something particular about this case, which makes it different from the one linked.

Comment: @Zelphir I'm not exactly sure which part you don't understand. `name` is just the parameter of the function getting wrapped and the wrapper as well.

Comment: I don't understand how it can be the parameter in one case but the function in the other case. How can it be two things?

Comment: Somehow SO doesn't let me include (at)nickname in the comments, sorry for that.