# How to declare decorator inside a class, to decorate an already decorated, inherited method?

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

I want to create a decorator which is a class member, and that is going to decorate an inherited method, which is decorated.

example code:

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def the_decorator(cls, decorated):  # <-----this is what i want, with or without self/cls as an argument
        def decorator()
            #do stuff before
            decorated()
            print "decorator was called!"
            #do stuff after
        return decorator

    @abstractmethod
    def inherited():
        raise NotImplemented


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()

    #@A.the_decorator <--- this is what I want, 
    @overrides
    #@A.the_decorator <--- or this
    def inherited():
        print "B.inherited was invoked"
```

and

```
b = B()
b.inherited()
```

should output

> B.inherited was invoked
>
> decorator was called!

---

Having read [this guide on decorators as class members](https://medium.com/@vadimpushtaev/decorator-inside-python-class-1e74d23107f6), I still haven't been able to figure out how to decorate inherited methods with decorators defined in the super class.

---

Note, here `@overrides` is defined by the `overrides` [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167617/in-python-how-do-i-indicate-im-overriding-a-method) `pip install overrides`

---

Also note i am currently using python 2.7, but would love both 2.7 and 3+ answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3, your code is just missing a few self arguments to be able to call the function with b.inherited()

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def the_decorator(cls, decorated): 
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            #do stuff before
            decorated(*args, **kwargs)
            print("decorator was called!")
            #do stuff after
        return decorator

    @abstractmethod
    def inherited(self):
        raise NotImplemented


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()

    @A.the_decorator
    @overrides
    def inherited(self):
        print("B.inherited was invoked")
```

Answer (score 2):

You were not that far!

The key is that a decorator will receive one single argument which is the decorated function so it can only be a statmethod. And you also forgot that normal methods should be declared with a `self` argument.

But this code should work:

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def the_decorator(decorated):  # <-----this is what i want, with or without self/cls as an argument
        def decorator(self):
            #do stuff before
            decorated(self)
            print "decorator was called!"
            #do stuff after
        return decorator

    @abstractmethod
    def inherited():
        raise NotImplemented


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()

    @A.the_decorator #<--- this is what I want, 
    @overrides
    #@A.the_decorator <--- or this
    def inherited(self):
        print "B.inherited was invoked"
```

I could test it under Python 2.7 except for the `@overrides` decorator (I commented it in my tests)

Comment: In the first link in the question, please look at the `Make it static (don’t)` part. Why is that different here?

Comment: @Gulzar That is an interesting question... I tested my code (with `@staticmethod`) in both Python 2.7 and 3.6 and it worked fine on both. But please note that in the linked post, the decorators are declared without the `cls` implicit argument despite being classmethods which I personally dislike.

Comment: @Gulzar The catch described in the `Make it static (don't)` paragraph only applies if the decorator is implemented as a static method _inside_ the class that is using it to decorate methods. Your example alerady employs the solution outlined in the `Declare in another class` paragraph, hence making the decorator method static is perfectly fine.