# can not override `route` method inside one of my models

Tags: django, wagtail

I want to override the `route` method from the `Page` wagtail model inside one of my models but it seems that it doesn't work, i am aware of the `RoutablePageMixin` that isn't what i want,Basically i tried to do something similar to what is in the [wagtail's doc](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#adding-endpoints-with-custom-route-methods)  like this:

```
class Echoer(Page):

    def route(self, request, path_components):
        print('inside route method')
        .
        .
        .
```

but i never see that print statement get executed when a request arrive for that page, can anyone please explain what is going on?Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I indicate I'm overriding a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167617/in-python-how-do-i-indicate-im-overriding-a-method)

Comment: Thank you @juankysmith , please have a look at wagtail's doc link.

Comment: Just tried the same code here (with `return super().route(request, path_components)` after the print), and it's working for me. Are you sure you're visiting the URL of a page of type `Echoer`?

Comment: Hello @gasman after doing some researches i discovered that the route method inside my model was this method:
    def _new_route(self, request, path_components):
    """
    Rewrite route method in order to handle languages fallbacks
    """
    # copied from wagtail/contrib/wag
    .
    .


and this was the result of adding my model to translation.py.
not the route method from the Page model which i was trying to override.