# @overrides module fails in Python

Tags: python, overriding

Following [this nice module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167617/in-python-how-do-i-indicate-im-overriding-a-method) I've been using for at least a year with no trouble, I am doing [as the doc says](https://github.com/mkorpela/overrides):

install with `pip install overrides`

`BaseSegmenter.py`

```
from overrides import EnforceOverrides

class BaseSegmenter(EnforceOverrides):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def segment_defects(self):
        pass
```

`DefectSegmenter.py`

```
from defect_segmentation import BaseSegmenter
from overrides import overrides


class AutoencoderSegmenter(BaseSegmenter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @overrides
    def segment_defects(self, inspected, warped, warp_mask):
        pass
```

This gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/noam/autoencoder1/Main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from defect_segmentation.DefectSegmenter import AutoencoderSegmenter
  File "C:\noam\autoencoder1\defect_segmentation\DefectSegmenter.py", line 5, in <module>
    class AutoencoderSegmenter(BaseSegmenter):
  File "C:\noam\autoencoder1\defect_segmentation\DefectSegmenter.py", line 9, in AutoencoderSegmenter
    @overrides
  File "C:\noam\autoencoder1\venv\lib\site-packages\overrides\overrides.py", line 67, in overrides
    raise AssertionError('No super class method found for "%s"' % method.__name__)
AssertionError: No super class method found for "segment_defects"
```

This happens when the following line executes:

```
from defect_segmentation.DefectSegmenter import AutoencoderSegmenter
```

I am probably missing something basic, but my eyes see the super class does indeed have `segment_defects`...

Help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `DefectSegmenter.py`

```
from defect_segmentation import BaseSegmenter
```

instead of the correct

```
from defect_segmentation.BaseSegmenter import BaseSegmenter
```

Which is a module, not a class. That made the reflection fail in the `@overrides` module.