# Should I use @Override tag when implementing an interface method?

Tags: java, annotations, overriding

Should I put the @Override tag if I am implementing a method of an interface? I know @Override tag should be there when you override a method of super class (not an interface). But how about implementing a method of an interface?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-a-method-that-implements-an-interface-method-be-annotated-with-override/212624#212624

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-a-method-that-implements-an-interface-method-be-annotated-with-override/212624#212624):

> You should use @Override whenever
>   possible.  It prevents simple mistakes
>   from being made.  Example:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public boolean equals(MyObject mObj){
>     // code ...
> }
> ```
>
> This doesn't compile because it
>   doesn't properly override equals.
>
> The same will go for methods that
>   implement an interface (1.6 and above
>   only) or override a Super class's
>   method.

Comment: But how come the netbeans IDE (and now the eclipse Helios) complains when I do something like:

new Comparator<Obj>(){
   @Override public int compare(Obj lhs, Obj rhs){
         .....
   }
}

The IDE suggests to remove the @Override tag

Comment: @dolaa, what version of java are you using?  1.5 does not allow annotating interface implementing like this.

Comment: But, you should definitely do it if you are using 1.6

Comment: @dola, well, it that case you cannot use the @Override annotation.