# If we have @Override why is there not @Implementation or @Implements`?

Tags: java, interface, annotations, design-decisions

I'm curious as to why we have the @Overrides annotation, but there is not a similar idiom for interfaces (such as @Implements or @Implementation).  It seems like it'd be a useful feature, as you could require the interface you are implementing to be a value of the annotation.

Was this a conscious decision or just an overlooked one?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-a-method-that-implements-an-interface-method-be-annotated-with-override), but it doesn't seem to discuss why there wasn't a separate annotation created.

Comment: Probably because it's not that big of a deal. `@Override` is sufficient. I guess you could write your own.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well, but that depends on how the compiler is implemented. If you created your own annotation that extended @Override, would the compiler check for it as well?

Comment: I think its because Java tends to be a minimalist language and every feature you add could break backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you don't need such an annotation, because if you don't implement the interface you will receive a compile-time error. The only case is if the class is `abstract`. There it can be useful. But then again you have the `@Override`, so a new annotation is probably useless.

Comment: And if you use @Override on an implemented interface method, you will get a compile error if that method disappears from the interface (which could be an indicator that you need to change your implementation).

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are implementing an `interface` (e.g. `public class AClass implements AInterface`), you are using that keyword `implements` which is enough info to let know that even if you are using `@Override`, the method is actually an implementation of an abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Override` annotation is merely a marker for the compiler. It exists so that the compiler can generate warnings where the developer's intentions are perhaps confused. The javadoc reads as follows:

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method
>   declaration in a superclass. If a method is annotated with this
>   annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers
>   are required to generate an error message.

Any `@Implements` annotation would probably only provide the same function, so its utility would be limited to the compiler.