# How to rectify the errors in the autogenerated IMarketBillingService.java file?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement `In app billing` service in my Andorid application.

I've added the `IMarketBillingService.aidl` file to my project in Eclipse. Then Eclipse autogenerated the `IMarketBillingService.java` file, but with many errors.

```
@Override public android.os.IBinder asBinder() { return mRemote; }
- implements android.os.IInterface.asBinder
- The method asBinder() of type IMarketBillingService.Stub.Proxy must override asuperclass  method

@Override public android.os.Bundle sendBillingRequest(android.os.Bundle bundle) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Bundle _result;
......
}
- The method sendBillingRequest(Bundle) of type IMarketBillingService.Stub.Proxy must override a superclass method
- implements com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService.sendBillingRequest
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I am using Mac, Eclipse Juno with last version of Android SDK.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You might try to use default compile options.

1. Right-click (or Control-Click) the project and select "Properties"
2. Select "Java Compiler"
3. Uncheck "Enable Project     Specific Settings"

Eclipse will prompt to re-compile and it should be all good.

Comment: For future reference, it's changing the Java compiler compliance level from 1.5 to 1.6+ that fixes this error. If you have to turn project-specific settings on or off to do so, that's incidental.

Answer (score 4):

Was also getting numerous errors in the generated IInAppBillingService.java. I tried many, many suggested solutions without success. Finally a variant of Zedifire's method worked on my Eclipse SDK.  (these steps are from memory - try around until it works!)

1. turned off >Project>Build Automatically
2. deleted the /gen files
3. THEN went to >Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler and found that somehow compliance level had defaulted to 1.5
4. changed compliance back to level 1.7
5. >Project>Clean
6. >Project>Build All (still errors!)
7. **Right clicked** on project window >android tools>fix project properties

VOILA -the generated files finally compiled without the errors!

Answer (score 1):

Project-->clean and build may solve it as well

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that Java 1.5 does not support overriding interface methods.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/212642/1283492
From Java 1.6 onwards it is allowed. Thus as already stated by easycheese, one needs to put Java 1.6 or higher in the java compiler settings of the project properties.