# Remove override method at asBinder in IMarketBilling.java for in app billing in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement in-app purchase to my product.I imported IMarketBilling.aidl to my project. It generated a .java file in my project with errors to remove override method near asBinder method.For that i changed my compiler to 1.6 and set JRE7 to JRE6.ofcourse i am cleaning the project for my every attempt.
The main issue is to access the IMarketBilling.aidl file in my project..But it is throwing errors to remove @override at asBinder() method.

Do any one have a good idea to resolve my issue

Comment: what is your issue ? please show your code

Comment: @Mehul1000 see my edited one

Comment: why you want to access IMarketBilling.aidl...you have to just change your public key which is in BillingSecuruty.java and the product id which in in Main Class

Comment: in documentation it is clearly said to import .aidl file @Mehul1000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have came through same problem.

I have just

**Right click on project -> Properties -> Java compiler to 1.6** -> **Apply -> Yes** and it will automatically rebuild the project and that will solve the above issue.

Refer the below link

[How to rectify the errors in the autogenerated IMarketBillingService.java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418476/errors-in-generated-imarketbillingservice-java-file)

You can try this option also

You might try to use default compile options.

- Right-click (or Control-Click) the project and select "Properties"
- Select "Java Compiler"
- Uncheck "Enable Project Specific Settings"
- Eclipse will prompt to re-compile and it should be all good.

Comment: It didnot help me so far :( @Nirali

Comment: Excellent solution to a very annoying problem