# BillingService in android app

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I wrote app with billing service and this app is on Google play store.

Today, I want update my code, but I have error in gen.

I removed gen and I have this error:

IMarketBillingService.java was removed! Recreating IMarketBillingService.java!

Please help me.
How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13563708/1441666

Right click on project -> Properties -> Java compiler to 1.6 -> Apply -> Yes and it will automatically rebuild the project and that will solve the above issue.

You can try this option also

You might try to use default compile options.

- Right-click (or Control-Click) the project and select "Properties"
- Select "Java Compiler" Uncheck "Enable Project Specific Settings"
- Eclipse will prompt to re-compile and it should be all good.