# Android billing library error

Tags: android, android-library, android-billing

everyone.
I just started with in app purchase in my application.
It's something new for me.
Now I've seen some examples on the net, I found that one project on github was full of errors before I linked the billing library to it.
When I did I just solved the errors in the project, but still got an exclamation red mark on it because the android billing library package has errors.
I checked the error, but I couldn't solve it, because I didn't understand how to.
Please guys, I really need some help.

I got the error in these lines

```
    @Override 
    public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
    {
        return this;
    }
```

in asBinder the error and its saying "Multiple markers at this line

```
- The method asBinder() of type IMarketBillingService.Stub must override a superclass method  
- implements android.os.IInterface.asBinder"
```

Same to this code also i getting an error

```
    @Override
    public android.os.Bundle sendBillingRequest(android.os.Bundle bundle) throws android.os.RemoteException     
    {
        android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
        android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
        android.os.Bundle _result;
        try {
            _data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
            if ((bundle!=null)) {
                _data.writeInt(1);
                bundle.writeToParcel(_data, 0);
            } else {
                _data.writeInt(0);
            }
            mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_sendBillingRequest, _data, _reply, 0);
            _reply.readException();
            if ((0!=_reply.readInt())) 
            {
                _result = android.os.Bundle.CREATOR.createFromParcel(_reply);
            } else {
                _result = null;
            }
        }
        finally {
            _reply.recycle();
            _data.recycle();
        }
        return _result;
    }
}

static final int TRANSACTION_sendBillingRequest = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 0);
}
```

I don't know what these errors are.
I just got this library as it is and placed it in my Eclipse project.
And the error is in InAppBillingService, which I can't access because it's auto generated!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue through these step i found by mistake in this site stackoverflow here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418476/errors-in-generated-imarketbillingservice-java-file

Comment: are u importing IMarketBillingService class or not

Comment: Follow the step to resolve the problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418476/how-to-rectify-the-errors-in-the-autogenerated-imarketbillingservice-java-file

Comment: You should reply and mark your own answer as accepted, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

It was getting a lot of errors in the generated IInAppBillingService.java. I tried many, many suggested solutions without success. Finally a variant of Zedifire's method worked on my Eclipse SDK. (these steps are from memory - try around until it works!)

turned off >Project>Build Automatically
deleted the /gen files
THEN went to >Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler and found that somehow compliance level had defaulted to 1.5
changed compliance back to level 1.7

> Project>Clean
>   Project>Build All (still errors!)
>   Right clicked on project window >android tools>fix project properties