# Why the setServletContext method of ServletContextAware interface is throwing an error?

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented the method as below but there is an error saying - remove override annotation, which should be there. Under which circumstances this error would occur? Due to this my beans are not being created and I am not able to run the application.

```
@Override
 public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
}
```

The error which shows up on the console is - "The method setServletContext(ServletContext) of type MenuHelper must override a superclass method". But the method is there and goes undetected. If I remove the method, there should be an error saying add the unimplemented methods - which is also not showing up. Kindly help me with this situation. Thanks

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-a-method-that-implements-an-interface-method-be-annotated-with-override)

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-a-method-that-implements-an-interface-method-be-annotated-with-override#comment92398_212624) comment

Comment: Check the target compiler version. Please use a compiler for  at least Java 6 or 7 runtime

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is javac failing on @Override annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation)

Comment: I have one more thing to add - I can build through ant and run tomcat separately and access the application's url. But the eclipse has some error. I have changed the build to Java 1.6 and jre6 is also there. Now where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without seeing the rest of your code, but from that error I'm guessing that your class does not implement `ServletContextAware` properly.