# To know if I have used interface, abstract, overload and override

Tags: java

I have developed a student registration system using java. I want to implement it using interface, abstraction overloading and overriding. Please let me know if I have used the concepts in my code below, any help would be highly appreciated. I am very new to java programming and still struggling how to use these concept in my code.

Comment: i can't see any overloading and abstraction concept implemented , interface and overriding is there though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Pavneet Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4936904/pavneet-singh) said you have used interfaces and overriding methods. These are shown by your `public interface insert_delete` and the line `@Override` above your methods.

You may be wondering why you override interface methods as by default they have no code in them but this is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212624/4601149).

As for the abstract part, you do not seem to of used it. You can read more about what an `abstract` class in `Java` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320887/4601149).

Finally, method overloading is where you have two or more methods with the same name but different arguments.

For example, you might have

```
public void insert() {
    //Your code
}

public void insert(int position) {
    //setPosition(position)
    //Rest of your code
}
```

So when you go back to see your code you will see you have not used this either. You can read more about it [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/)

I hope this helps clear some things up for you

Comment: sir if i add public void insert(String query, String msg) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        conn=connect_to_mysql.getConnection();

Comment: sir if i add     public void insert(String query, String msg) throws                         ClassNotFoundException {
        conn=connect_to_mysql.getConnection();   this except second insert method will it be overload?

Comment: @AlexDRex Yes that will be. Just remember to put it in a try catch block if you use it as you throw an exception