# Why Override an Interface method?

Tags: java, java-8, interface, overriding

When extending an abstract class I understand why you would have to over ride some methods. But when it comes to interfaces I do not understand why it must be done. If all methods of an interface must be implemented, what is the use of overriding them?.

Im talking about the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Are you talking about the the `@Override` annotation? Or is it the wording of "overriding" vs. "implementing" that is confusing you?

Comment: Im talking about the @Override annotation

Comment: you should check this SO's page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-we-override-an-interfaces-method-implementation

Answer (score 6):

Using `@Override` is purely optional. You don't have to use it. If you do, using `@Override` when implementing an interface has more or less the same reasoning as using it when extending an abstract class. In a nutshell, it prevents stupid mistakes - if an interface is changed, it forces you to change your class accordingly, instead of just tacking on the "new" methods you suddenly need to implement.

Comment: I understand that. But wouldn't the compiler give an error if there is an unimplemented method in which case it would act as a check.

Comment: @MphiweNtuli sure, the same way it would if you're extending an abstract class.

Comment: @MphiweNtuli the compiler tells you when you forgot to implement a method, but it won’t tell you when a method supposed to implement a method actually doesn’t. You seem to think of implementing *n* interface methods with *n* actual methods, so a mismatch will be spotted. But what if you have *n* methods, but the interface actually has *n-1* methods? You’ve implemented all methods, but one method is not doing what it is supposed to do. With `@Override`, the compiler will tell you.

Comment: @Holger That actually makes sense. I tested it and it behaves like that. I will continue using Override then